# process re-parenting: controlling who is the new parent

Tags: unix, process, fork, orphan, process-reaper

Is the new parent always "init" or **is there some way to control who gets to be the new parent**?

Wikipedia seems indicates that it's always "init". I really hope that this is not the case. I have tried everything I can think of with setpgid and setsid, but no luck. And now that I see this wikipedia article I need advice.

> In a Unix-like operating system any
>   orphaned process will be immediately
>   adopted by the special init system
>   process. This operation is called
>   re-parenting and occurs automatically.
>   Even though technically the process
>   has the "init" process as its parent,
>   it is still called an orphan process
>   since the process that originally
>   created it no longer exists.
>   [Taken from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process)

The reason I'm asking is because I'm making a Mac app that runs a number of worker processes. I want these worker processes to appear as children of the main process in the process-hierarchy of the [task manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_Monitor). Some of the workers run as different users and on Mac OS X I need to fork twice to pass privileges to the child process. Because I "double fork" the workers currently run as deamons, and when looking with task manager I see the workers are having "init" as their parent process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Orphaned children are always adopted by `init`. There is no `Unix` way of changing the parent to some non-init process.

---

As of Linux 3.4 this is no longer strictly true. There's still no portable Unix way of doing this but as Andy Lutomirski points out Linux 3.4 adds `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` for [`prctl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html).

> In effect, a subreaper fulfills the role of `init(1)` for its
>   descendant processes.

Answer (score 11):

On Linux, you can use PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER to indicate that your orphaned descendants should be re-parented to you instead of to init.

Answer (score 1):

I think reptyr can perform what you want. Check it out:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/reptyr

https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr