# Reassigning Parent PID

Tags: objective-c, c, exec, fork, authorizationservices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [process re-parenting: controlling who is the new parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476452/process-re-parenting-controlling-who-is-the-new-parent)

I'm writing a small tool to help me launch my helper tools (because AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivilages is horrifying to use) but when I do fork()/execve() in my NSTask-like wrapper class, it forks as a child process of the helper tool. How would I get it to fork as a child process of the originating parent (the parent of the small tool launching my helper tools)? I've tried setpgid(0, parent_pid); after the fork but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

A child process will always have a new pid. However, you can do the exec in the parent process and thus keep the pid. This works only once tho. :-)

Comment: So you're saying I can execve() without fork() and somehow keep the same parent pid? Elaborate please?