# Launching script that launches programs and waiting for them to finish in Python

Tags: python, linux, perl, subprocess, python-os

I have a Perl script that launches some programs and then ends while the programs run in the background. I would like to write a Python script that will be able to wait for those launched programs to finish, not just for the Perl script.

I tried this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(('./perl_script.pl'))
```

and this:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(('./perl_script.pl'))
p.wait()
```

but in both cases program finishes when the perl_script.pl finishes, and not when the launched programs do.

Comment: Why not just wait in the perl script until the launched programs end? That sounds a lot easier than controlling programs from one script that were launched in another.

Comment: Traditionally unix doesn't support this; orphaned processes are inherited by the init process. But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476452/process-re-parenting-controlling-who-is-the-new-parent. (Hard to see how you'd utilize that for your use case, especially from python.)

Comment: @GilHamilton: `prctl(PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER)` can be called in Python using `ctypes`. But I would try `shell=True` and redirecting stdin/stdout/stderr first.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know PERL and it's a very long script... (yay for old scripts from phd advisors)